# SDL2 errors on Visual studio Code while setting it up

Tags: c, json, visual-studio-code, sdl, sdl-2

I recently wanted to try out SDL2 using C and  I followed this [tutorial](https://programmer.help/blogs/vscode-sdl2-configuration-tutorial.html)
Once everything was done I ran the code but I came across an error I did search the web but I did not find any clear answer

```
.\main.c:1:22: fatal error: SDL2/SDL.h: No such file or directory
 #include <SDL2/SDL.h>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
```

This was my configuration for

c_cpp_properties.json

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                //Pay attention to change to your own MinGW directory
                "C:\\MinGW\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include\\**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

launch.json

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            //Pay attention to change to your own MinGW directory
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json

```
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++.exe build active file",
            //Pay attention to change to your own MinGW directory
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-lmingw32",
                "-lSDL2main",
                "-lSDL2",
                "-mwindows"
            ],
            "options": {
                //Pay attention to change to your own MinGW directory
                "cwd": "C:\\MinGW\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have also included the SDL2.dll in the root directory
I have copied the 64bit folder of the SDL2

Thanks.

Edit: This is the code that was running in the main.c file

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
//#include <stdio.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>


SDL_Window *window = NULL;
SDL_Surface *surface = NULL;

//The parameters in the main function cannot be omitted, or an error will be reported
int main(int arg, char *argv[])
{
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL2 Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (!window)
        return -1;
    surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    if (!surface)
        return -2;

    SDL_Rect rec;
    rec.x = 700;
    rec.y = 10,
    rec.w = 20;
    rec.h = 20;

    while (1)
    {
        SDL_FillRect(surface, &rec, SDL_MapRGB(surface->format, 180, 10, 140));

        rec.x += 6;
        rec.y += 2;
        rec.x = rec.x > 800 ? 0 : rec.x;
        rec.y = rec.y > 600 ? 0 : rec.y;

        SDL_FillRect(surface, &rec, SDL_MapRGB(surface->format, 10, 200, 120));

        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
        SDL_Delay((1.0 / 60) * 1000);
    }

    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have added the code which was written on the file main.c

Comment: This question is closed thanks a lot to Holy black cat for helping me out